# Define a responsive square grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need help doing a CSS task. I have done the following setup:

```js
function ind2sub(siz,ind){
    rowsub = Math.floor(ind/siz[1])
    colsub = ind % siz[1]
    return [rowsub,colsub]
}
function sub2ind(siz,rowsub,colsub){
    return siz[1]*Math.floor(rowsub)+Math.floor(colsub)
}

    var rows = 7
    var cols = 7
    for(i = 0;i<rows*cols;i++){
        var probe = $('<span data-id="'+i+'" data-selected="0" class="probe" style="font-size:6px;">'+i+'</span>')
          $('#mcuframe').append(probe)
    }
    ind = sub2ind([rows,cols],rows/2,cols/2)
    $('#mcuframe .probe[data-id="' + ind +'"]').addClass("fieldselected")//.css("background-color","lightblue")

    rows = 14
    cols = 19
    for(i = 0;i<rows*cols;i++){
        var sample = $('<span data-id="'+i+'" data-selected="0" class="sample" style="font-size:6px;">'+i+'</span>')
          $('#fovframe').append(sample)
    }
    ind = sub2ind([rows,cols],rows/2,cols/2)
    $('#fovframe .sample[data-id="'+ind+'"]').addClass("fieldselected")//css("background-color","lightblue")
    
    $('.probe,.sample').click(function(){
        if($(this).hasClass('probe')){
            $('.probe').removeClass('fieldselected')
            $(this).addClass("fieldselected")
        }
        else if($(this).hasClass('sample')){
            $('.sample').removeClass('fieldselected')
            $(this).addClass("fieldselected")
        }
    });
    
    $('#move2samplebtn').click(function () {
        /*if ($('#con_mcu_tgl').prop("checked") == false) {
            return
        }*/
        var probeidx = ind2sub([7,7], $('.probe.fieldselected').data('id'))
        var sampleidx = ind2sub([14,19], $('.sample.fieldselected').data('id'))
        
    });
```

```css
#mcuframe {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(7, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(7, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 2px;
  background-color: black;
  border: solid 2px black;
}

#mcuframe .probe {
  background-color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#mcuframe .probe:hover{
  background-color: gray;
}

#mcuframe .probe::before {
  content: "";
  padding-top: 100%;
  float: left;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

#fovframe {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(19, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(14, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 2px;
  background-color: black;
  border: solid 2px black;
}

#fovframe .sample {
  background-color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#fovframe .sample:hover{
  background-color: gray;
}

#fovframe .sample::before {
  content: "";
  padding-top: calc(100% / 19 * 14);
  float: left;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}
.fieldselected{
  background-color:lightblue !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
<main role="main" class="col-md-9 ml-sm-auto col-lg-10 px-4">
  <div class="d-flex justify-content-between flex-wrap flex-md-nowrap align-items-center pt-3 pb-2 mb-3 border-bottom">
    <h1 class="h2">Dashboard</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="container" style="padding: 0px; margin: 0px;">
    <div class="row" style="padding: 0px; margin: 0px;">
      <div class="col-lg-9">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist" id="controltabs">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#movpanel" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
              <i class="fa fa-arrows-alt"></i>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>

        <div class="tab-content">
          <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="movpanel">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-header">
                Move panel
              </div>
              <div class="card-body">
              
                      <div style="width: 48%; float:left">
                        <h4>1) Choose probe</h4>
                        <div id="mcuframe"></div>
                      </div>

                      <div style="width: 48%; float:right">
                        <h4>2) Choose sample </h4>
                        <div id="fovframe"></div>
                      </div>

                      <div class="clearfix"></div>

                      <div class="row no-gutters mt-4">
                        <div class="col">
                          <button class="btn btn-success col-12" id="move2samplebtn">
                            Move to chosen sample
                          </button>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
    </div>
  </div>
```

This kinda works, but my problem here is primarily that the surrounding frame under 2) is not square, but also that the text breaks the surrounding container on smaller screens. Both frames under 1) and 2) should always be square and have same size regardless of windowsize(responsive design). Also, if i change the number of the grid cells either horizontally or vertically or both it should remain square under same conditions as described above. Its the boxes inside the frame which needs to change aspect ratio when the number of boxes in either direction changes. I have tried using a css grid approach as shown in the fiddle, but this is not doing the job as i expected. What am I doing wrong here since the grid does not remain square?

Comment: how are you planning to make that square by 14 rows and 19 columns

Comment: by having nonsquare boxes inside the square containers. I.e. each of the 14x19 boxes are of course not square, but the container is

Comment: why not providing width and height?? when you dont want the size of the container to change. you can give width and height static

Comment: I dont mind that the size of the container changes - in fact it should change to utilize the screen space best possible. I just want to maintain aspect ratio of 1 of the container